# Django Model not being updated after calling save() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

Im Using `django signals` to update a foreign key object of a model .

```
@receiver(sender=PointItem, signal=post_save)
def PointItemSaved(instance, sender, **kwargs):
    try:
        print(f"before save {user.points}")
        user = User.objects.get(id=instance.user.id)
        user.points += 100
        user.save()
        print(f"after save {user.points}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"there is a problem {e}")
```

according to logs , everything is correct .

before & after values are correct .

but when i check it on admin page it does not changed !

Update :

it works when i try to save `PointItem` from django Admin .

This problem occurs when i try to save object from api calls .

Answer (score 0):

Instance is the actual object, try
`instance.save()`

Comment: instance.save() will made this in infinite loop , coz of post_save signal

Comment: i tried to get User from individual Query to make it independent from instance

Comment: User model is individual hence it is not updating the instance object. You will have to associate your individual User object with instance.user object and then you can save your instance.